# How to create J2me(java)Project combining with J2me Polish

Tags: java-me, j2mepolish, midp-2.0

Hiii
i am new to J2me Apps,i have a requirement to develop tabs creation in my j2me (java)MIDP Programming,i come to know through google,j2me polish is better option to create tabs,i want to append LCDUI list screen to j2me polish's Tab1 and Tab2 etc.....

cany any one sample progam with mixing these two,i dont in my app where to create css file and how to combine MIDP Program with j2me polish,I have searched in google for Example Program's,but I am not able to get the samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add LCDUI List in a Polish tabbed pane.

To better understand how to change your screens from LCDUI to Polish, please go through the tutorial available at http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/tutorial/